# Как бороться с namespace в php?

Tags: php, классы, namespace

В приложении есть базовые классы, для быстрого доступа они не имеют спейсов, они часто используются в модулях, например:

```
namespace module;

class MyClass extends \BaseClass {
    public function __construct() {
        \TempClass::...;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Писать перед каждым классом `\гадость` очень не очень выглядит и читается

Хотелось бы что-то такое:

```
class module\MyClass extends BaseClass {
    public function __construct() {
        TempClass::...;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Класс `MyClass` я вызываю всего один раз, а базовые на каждом шагу. Есть способ сделать что-то с этим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте задание алиасов имен при помощи оператора [use](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php)

```
use BaseClass
```

Answer (score 2):

Не надо бороться. Используйте директиву `use` для  разового объявления какой класс надо использовать.

```
<?php

namespace foo\bar;
use some\large\namespace\someclass;

...
$obj = new someclass;
```

И прочие действия доступны просто по имени объявленного в `use` класса. При необходимости, можно и алиас использовать.